# How to select listview item when clicking button

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Inside my listview I´ve created a control template. Inside this template I made a button, so that every item inside mit listview has a button. This button represents an link which opens the directory that is shown. When I click the button, my program opens the explorer as I expect it. But when I click the button of an item that is not selected it opens the path of the selected item. So my question is, how can I change the selected item when I click the button inside my listview.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see "R1" is selected, but I click on the link of "R3". What happens is, that C:\Temp\Folder1 gets opened, because "R1" is still the selecteditem. What I wish to is that C:\Temp\Folder3 gets opend. I think the trick should be that "R3" gets selected when clicking the button that represents the link. Does anyone know how to that?

This is my XAML-Code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" FontSize="20" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMember, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="7,10,7,0" x:Name="ListView1" SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header 1" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header 2" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header 3" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header 4" Width="560"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header 5" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="560"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Path}" Style="{StaticResource Link}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.GoToPathCommand }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabled}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="4" Content="{Binding Owner}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.GoToPathCommand }"
```

This Command will jump to the Cmd of the `ViewModel`. I assume that the Command  will check which item is selected and it will access it's property `Path`.

Avoiding this behavior, You can create a Command that will take a parameter and set it from Binding:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path}"
    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                   AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.GoToPathCommand }"
CommandParameter="{Binding Path}"/>
```

Now the command itself must be adjusted:

```
public MyCmd : ICommand
{

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        string path = (string) parameter;
        //Open the path via explorer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below trigger too in the ListViewItem Style

```
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                  </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: That is nearly what I´m looking for, but it causes another problem. Clicking the button works fine now. But when I select "R1" and click on the "Accept" button the focus on the selected item get´s lost.